# Tuple as a key in Hadoop mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to use a "tuple" of 2 elements as a key in my mapreduce job.

I.e. I want my map task to output pair of `(first_key,second_key), value`

I tried using `ArrayWritable`, but after running my code I've got an error and it turned out that `ArrayWritable` isn't suitable for such task as it doesn't implement `WritableComparable` (whatever it means) and so, cannot be used as a key.

Strangely I cannot find any "right" solution for my problem that will work 100% with no strings attached. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

**Any key in a MapReduce job must implement [WritableComparable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html)** which not the case of `ArrayWritable`.

It must be `Comparable` too so that Hadoop can sort the (key,value) pairs.
 So in your case, a solution could be  to create your own class that implements `WritableComparable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implement `WritableComparable` you could use `new Text(key1.toString() + "\t" + key2.toString())` as key.